# org-refile is always returning with the message no refile targets

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Even though I have org files in my org-agenda-files, org-refile is saying no refile targets.
org-cycle-agenda-files is actually cycling between org files. so i guess the org-agenda-files is proper. can someone help me understand what i am missing here?

Comment: Could you provide the current value of `org-refile-targets`, `org-agenda-files` and `org-refile-target-verify-function`?  It's likely one of them is set to something that won't match any headlines.

Comment: org-refile-targets
Its value is ((nil :maxlevel . 9) (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 9))
Original value was nil


org-agenda-files
Its value is ("~/myOrgFiles" "~/myOrgFiles/office" "~/myOrgFiles/personal")

Original value was nil

org-refile-target-verify-function
Its value is bh/verify-refile-target
Original value was nil

Comment: (defun bh/verify-refile-target ()
  (not (member (nth 2 (org-heading-components)) org-done-keywords)))

Comment: For testing purposes, try setting `org-refile-target-verify-function` to 'nil temporarily.  Since minimally the `(nil :maxlevel . 9)` should provide you all the headlines in your current buffer, regardless of agenda files.

Comment: I get this error when trying this: `Wrong type argument: symbolp, (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 9)`

Answer (score 1):

A code block from Steve Purcell's .emacs.d which is solve that problem

```
; Targets include this file and any file contributing to the agenda - up to 5 levels deep
(setq org-refile-targets '((nil :maxlevel . 5) (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 5)))
```